# on duplicate key update on multiple unique constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a unique constraint on two columns.  I'm trying to user on duplicate key update but am getting an error...

... create the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requests` (
  `userFrom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userTo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `userFrom` (`userFrom`,`userTo`)
)
```

... add some data

```
INSERT INTO requests (userFrom, userTo) VALUES (1, 2)
```

... then this fails (when passed userFrom of 1 and userTo of 2

```
INSERT INTO requests (userFrom, userTo) VALUES (:userFrom, :userTo) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set dateSent = NOW()
```

Error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set dateSent = NOW()' at line 1
```

Comment: Your DB is stores users as `INT`? Why? Common sense dictates that a user would be a string of characters. Your users are stored as numbers? How odd.

Comment: @bobthyasian it's an FK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think there is no needed for `set` keyword here, try this

```
INSERT INTO requests (userFrom, userTo) VALUES (:userFrom, :userTo) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dateSent = NOW()
```